# Histogram with ggplot2 requires a continuous x variable

Tags: linux, r, graph, rstudio

I have a dataset in a table format that looks like this:

```
            test frequency
1         test40         3
2         test33         5
3         test19         2
4       test4521         1
5         test34         1
6         test27         3
7         test42         3
8         test35         1
....
```

If I use this command:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(t, aes("frequency")) +
  geom_histogram()
```

("t" is the name of my table)

Then RStudio says: "StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?"

I just want to see how many times a 3 or a 5 etc. occurs.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your data is already aggregated? Maybe the `ggplot2::geom_histogram()` function might not appropriate for you to use? Have you tried the `geom_col()` function? This simply takes the numbers declared in the input data frame, and displays a column plot with that data.

Using the below code

```
# Declare data frame
t <- data.frame(test = c("test40", "test33", "test19", "test4521",
                         "test34", "test27", "test42", "test35"),
                frequency = c(3, 5, 2, 1,
                              1, 3, 3, 1))
```

returns the data frame like this

```
# View data
print(t)

      test frequency
1   test40         3
2   test33         5
3   test19         2
4 test4521         1
5   test34         1
6   test27         3
7   test42         3
8   test35         1
```

and therefore you can plot it like this

```
# Load package
library(ggplot2)

# Generate column plot
ggplot(t, aes(test, frequency)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image: Column plot for 't']

If you simply wanted a count of the times that the number 2 or the number 3 occurred in your data frame, then yes the `geom_histogram()` is the correct function to use. See, the `geom_histogram()` function counts the frequency that a term occurs in the data frame, then returns the result. It has an internal validation that looks at the type of data that you are trying to plot across the x-axis, and notices that if it is discrete, then you need to parse the parameter `stat="count"` in the function. If you don't include this parameter, then ggplot will try to bin your data to create the histogram, which is illogical because all you want is a count.

Check out this link for a description of the difference between continuous and discrete data: [What is the difference between discrete data and continuous data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206/what-is-the-difference-between-discrete-data-and-continuous-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

With this in mind, you can plot the histogram like this

```
# Generate histogram plot
ggplot(t, aes(frequency)) +
    geom_histogram(stat="count")
```

[image: Histogram plot for 't']

I hope that helps mate.